# Cross domain authentication... How?

Tags: javascript, authentication, cross-domain

I'm working on a web application where users will create accounts. Then clients will be about to have a section on their site for users to login with my sites login credentials. However... I don't want the clients site to be able to see or handle their login credentials. I am wanting to do cross domain authentication just like facebook connect does.

I have done research and it looks like I will need to create a javascript library that users will need to add into their site. Inside that javascript file I will need to create an iframe that will connect to my main site. From there a cookie will need to be placed then checked.

Does anyone know of well written tutorials on how to do this or could you explain in detail on what all will need to be done?

EDIT:
How would the storing and reading of cookies work. Anyone have examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be a plain iframe. Twitter does it a lot. If your have to communicate with the parent site for some reason, try building an API with the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) function.